# Assigning a boolean value to a function based on whether it ran without error

Tags: python, selenium

Im writing a test case using Selenium and Pytest. So far, each of the individual tests focus on a single aspect of a web app I'm developing, and I want to test them all using pytest.

My problem is this:
right now, the functions I am using to write my test cases have no output, which means I cannot use the `assert` method to check if the test passed or failed. 
What I would like to do is have each function return `True` or `False` based on whether it ran with our error or no. That way I can use the `assert` to make sure the program ran without fail

```
def sign_in():
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button/span[text()= "SIGN IN"]').click()
```

Is there a way to modify or write this function in a different way such that if an error occurs, it return `False`, and if no error occurs, it returns `True`?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Don't do that. Catch the exceptions thrown. If you are using pytest, the test will fail if any error is thrown, so you can just call your function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try/except`

```
def sign_in():
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button/span[text()= "SIGN IN"]').click()
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```